# Why does the notation for an "array of pointers to different arrays" match the notation of a traditional 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

In the book *C Programming: A Modern Approach*, the author declares and initializes the following array of pointers to different strings:

```
char *planets[9] = {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth",...,"Pluto"};
```

Subsequently, the author comments:

> ...accessing a character in a planet name is done in the same way as accessing an element of a two-dimensional array. To search the `planets` array for strings beginning with letter M, for example, we could use the following loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  if (planets[i][0] == 'M')
    printf("%s begins with M \n", planets[i]);
```

I think I have a good understanding of 2D (and, more generally, n-multidimensional) arrays and how different notations allow you to treat your notation as if it were a pointer. For example, in a 3D array named `3D_arr`, you could use `3D_arr[i][j]` or `3D_arr[i]` as different "pointer-like" entities to navigate the matrix.

However, at the end of the day, this 3D array is one big row-arranged block of contiguous memory.

My confusion with the notation that the author employs to navigate an array of pointers to different arrays is that I don't see the connection with a standard 2D array. **The blocks of memory are no longer contiguous, are they?** Any explanation is greatly appreciated.

Edit: Is the notation `planets[i]`, itself, functioning as a pointer name (and then we are subsequently indexing off of that)? ...So `planets[i]` could be thought of as an alias name for some pointer variable (call it `alias`) and we are really just doing `alias[j]`?

Comment: Yes, the edit is correct. `planets` is an array of pointers. `planets[i]` is a pointer, and that pointer points to the first character of an array of characters.

Comment: There is of course a difference between `char a1[dim1][dim2]` and `char* a2[dim]`. But since the compiler knows the different types of `a1` and `a2`, respectively, it can generate the correct code for each of `a1[index1][index2]` and `a2[index1][index2]`.

Comment: You initialize the array of pointers with *String Literals* which are themselves character arrays. When you access an array, it is converted to a pointer to the first element -- which is how the initialization is working in your case (see [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)) . The same applies to your *array-of-pointers*. So when you access the array `planets` it is converted to a pointer to it's first element (which is a pointer), so you have a *pointer-to-pointer* (2-levels of indirection) which `[][]` remove 1 level each to reference each char.

Comment: The confusion here is caused by the author’s poor wording that the access is done “in the same way.” They simply mean that the same source code form is used, not that the same source code form results in the same actual actions inside the computer. Indeed, an array of pointers and an array of arrays are handled differently in spite of the latter going through a notional conversion to pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The in-memory view of the `planets` array would be something like this:

```
      planets                           --
           +----+    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--+   |
 planets[0]|    |--->|M|e|r|c|u|r|y|\0|   |
           |    |    +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--+   |
           +----+    +-+-+-+-+-+--+       |
 planets[1]|    |--->|V|e|n|u|s|\0|       |
           |    |    +-+-+-+-+-+--+       |
           +----+    +-+-+-+-+-+--+       |
 planets[2]|    |--->|E|a|r|t|h|\0|        > Null terminated char array (string)
           |    |    +-+-+-+-+-+--+       |
           +----+                         |
             |                            |
             |                            |
             |                            |
           +----+    +-+-+-+-+-+--+       |
 planets[7]|    |--->|P|l|u|t|o|\0|       |
           |    |    +-+-+-+-+-+--+       |
           +----+                       --
```

Yes, you are correct. The internal representation of array of `char *` is different from a `2D` array of `char`.

Below is the detail about how `planets[i]` and `planets[i][0]` access works?

From C Standard#6.5.2.1:

> The definition of the subscript operator `[]` is that `E1[E2]` is identical to `(*((E1)+(E2)))`.

So, this

```
planets[i]
```

is equivalent to

```
(*(planets + i))
```

If `i` is `0` then this will result in

```
(*(planets + 0)) -> (*(planets)) -> *planets
```

which is first element of `planets`<sup>1)</sup> i.e. pointer to string literal `Mercury`.

When you access `0`<sup>th</sup> element of this pointer to string literal, you will get letter `M`.

Same is for other values of `i` - `1`, `2` ..., `7`.

That means, `planets[i][0]` will result in first character of `i`<sup>th</sup> string of `planets` array.

You can also look it in this way:

```
planets[i][0] -> (*(planets[i] + 0)) -> (*(*(planets + i)+0))
```

`(*(*(planets + i)+0))` will result in first character of `i`<sup>th</sup> string.

Also, `planets` is array of `8` `char` pointers and in the `for` loop you are accessing it one element beyond its range which is undefined behaviour:

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) // the loop will iterate 9 times -> i = 0 to 8
                ^^
```

The loop condition should be `i < 8`, so that it will access `planets` array till `7`<sup>th</sup> index - `planets[0]`, `planets[1]`, ...., `planets[7]`.

Hope this helps.

---

1).

- When you access an array, it is converted to a pointer to first element (there are few [exceptions](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) to this rule).
- When you increment a pointer, **it gets incremented in steps of the object size that the pointer can point to**.

The type of `planets` is `char *[8]` i.e. `planets` is an array of `8` `char *`. When we use it in an expression, it is converted to `char **`.
Size of a pointer may be `4` bytes or `8` bytes or something else based on underlying platform/architecture.

Assume that the size of pointer is `8` bytes (`64` bit architecture) and base address of `planets` array is `100`.

When we do `planets + 1`, the result of this expression would be `108` which is address of second element of `planets` array and when we dereference this address, we get the `"Venus"` string literal pointer.

Comment: The ASCII art alone is worth the UV! (a picture is worth 1000 words...)